# Checked items in Multiple Choice Dialog

Tags: android

I'm displaying a List of Objects in a MultipleChoiceDialog. Another List contains all Objects who are already checked.

My Lists:

```
List<Participant> participants = datasourceParticipant.getAllParticipants();
List<Participant> participantsConference = datasourceParticipant.getAllParticipants(conference.getId());
```

In order to display them in the MultipleChoiceDialog, I build my List like this:

```
participantsNames = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < this.participants.size(); i++) {
                participantsNames.add(i, participants.get(i).getFirstname() + " " + participants.get(i).getLastname());
}

participantConferenceNames = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < this.participantsConference.size(); i++) {
            participantConferenceNames.add(i, participantsConference.get(i).getFirstname() + " " + participantsConference.get(i).getLastname());
}
```

Afterwards, I create the necessary String array ...

```
final CharSequence[] items = participantsNames.toArray(new CharSequence[participantsNames.size()]);
```

to display it in the MultipleChoiceDialog

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, null);
```

How do I add the checkedItems to the MultipleChoiceDialog. Or is there a much easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in a `boolean[]` instead of null with the values that you want checked. The most straightforward way to accomplish this is to use a set:

```
 Set<Participant> set = new HashSet();
 set.addAll(datasourceParticipant.getAllParticipants(conference.getId()));
 boolean[] checked = new boolean[participants.size()];
 for (int i =0; i < participants.size(); i ++) {
   checked[i] = set.contains(participants.get(i));
 } 
 ....
 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checked, null);
```

For that to work your Participant class must implement `hashCode()`;

Comment: for some reasons, it's only working out the second, third and fourth time (etc.). But it's not working for the first time.